# How do you protect fragile commands or commands in general inside \bib* fields of amsrefs?

Tags: bibliographies, amsrefs, protected-macro, fragile

I would like to kindly inquire how to protect commands (which I would normally presume to be fragile) in the non-citable `\bib*` bibliographic fields of the package `amsrefs`.

Consider the following MWE1, taken from pages 13–14 of the [amsrdoc.pdf](https://ctan.um.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsrdoc.pdf) documentation of the `amsrefs` package (version January 16, 2013):

```
%MWE1
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}

\cite{Burkholder1986a}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\bib{Burkholder1986a}{article}{
    author={Burkholder, Donald L.},
    title={Martingales and Fourier analysis in Banach spaces},
    conference={
        title={C.I.M.E. Lectures},
        address={Varenna, Italy},
        date={1985}
    },
    book={
        series={Lecture Notes in Math.},
        volume={1206},
        publisher={Springer-Verlag},
        address={Berlin and New York},
        date={1986},
    },
    pages={61--108},
    review={\MR{0864712}}
}

\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

In MWE1, we are using only `\bib`, and there are no `\bib*` commands.
MWE1 compiles properly.

Now, consider the following MWE2, where we modified MWE1 a little bit and tried to separate book/journal information from the article information (we will use the `xref` field this time):

```
%MWE2
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}

\cite{Burkholder1986a-citable-whole-journal}

\cite{Burkholder1986a-citable-article-example}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\bib*{Burkholder1986a-not-citable}{article}{
    conference={
        title={C.I.M.E. Lectures},
        address={Varenna, Italy},
        date={1985}
    },
    book={
        series={Lecture Notes in Math.},
        volume={1206},
        publisher={Springer-Verlag},
        address={Berlin and New York},
        date={1986},
    },
}
    
\bib{Burkholder1986a-citable-whole-journal}{article}{
    xref={Burkholder1986a-not-citable},
}
    
\bib{Burkholder1986a-citable-article-example}{article}{
    xref={Burkholder1986a-not-citable},
    author={Burkholder, Donald L.},
    title={Martingales and Fourier analysis in Banach spaces},
    pages={61--108},
    review={\MR{0864712}}
}

\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

In MWE2, we used `\bib*` to hold non-citable book/journal information, and `\bib` to hold citable information. We can use `\bib*` so that we don't have to repeat information: common book/journal information is placed in one container, and separate/individual article information is placed in other containers.

For example, to cite the whole journal, we can use `\cite{Burkholder1986a-citable-whole-journal}`. To cite a particular article, like the one given above, we can use `\cite{Burkholder1986a-citable-article-example}`. All of these ideas were based on what I read in [amsrdoc](https://ctan.um.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsrdoc.pdf).

Also, as per [amsrdoc](https://ctan.um.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsrdoc.pdf), the `\bib*` fields in MWE2 are treated as moving arguments, and thus, all fragile commands must be protected. However, in this example, there are no "commands" in the `\bib*` fields in MWE2 (they are just text, strings), thus it is safe at the moment.

However, we also observe in MWE2 that there is a command in a field of `\bib`: the `\MR` command inside the review field. I assumed here (just for the sake of discussion) that the Mathematical Reviews number `{0864712}` refers to the particular article, and not the whole journal.

MWE2 compiles properly, just like MWE1.

Now, consider MWE3, where we further made some temporary "modifications" in MWE2 so that commands will appear in the `\bib*` fields, just to test the waters, so to speak:

```
%MWE3
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}

\cite{Burkholder1986a-citable-whole-journal}

\cite{Burkholder1986a-citable-article-example}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\bib*{Burkholder1986a-not-citable}{article}{
    conference={
        title={C.I.M.E. \protect\MakeUppercase{L}ectures},
        address={Varenna, Italy},
        date={1985}
    },
    book={
        series={Lecture Notes in Math.},
        volume={1206},
        publisher={Springer-Verlag},
        address={Berlin and New York},
        date={1986},
    },
    review={\protect\MR{0864712}}
    }
    
\bib{Burkholder1986a-citable-whole-journal}{article}{
    xref={Burkholder1986a-not-citable},
    }
    
\bib{Burkholder1986a-citable-article-example}{article}{
    xref={Burkholder1986a-not-citable},
    author={Burkholder, Donald L.},
    title={Martingales and Fourier analysis in Banach spaces},
    pages={61--108},
    }

\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

In MWE3, the `\MakeUppercase` command appears in the title field within the conference compound field. This is, for example, if I want to ensure that `Lectures` will always be capitalized. Also in MWE3, we assumed at the moment that the Mathematical Reviews number refers to the whole journal, and not to the article. Therefore, the `\MR` command is inside `\bib*`. Thus, with these temporary changes, we can see that there are now commands inside the `\bib*` field.

It says in [amsrdoc](https://ctan.um.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsrdoc.pdf) that `\bib*` fields are treated as moving arguments, and therefore, fragile commands must be protected. I understand this as putting `\protect` before the commands `\MakeUppercase` and `\MR` (I am assuming they are fragile). That is why `\protect` is shown in MWE3.

MWE3 DOES NOT compile properly. If I remove the `\protect` commands in MWE3, still MWE3 DOES NOT compile. I am assuming that MWE3 does not compile properly because I have not properly protected the commands `\MakeUppercase` and `\MR`. If I wanted to include commands within the fields inside `\bib*`, like the example in MWE3, how do I protect them?

I consider this concern very important, because I wanted to separate common whole-book/whole-journal information from individual article information. Using `amsrefs`, it seems the only way to do this is using `\bib*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any need for `\MakeUppercase{L}`, because no case change is applied: otherwise you'd have to do it also for C.I.M.E.

The *real* problem is in `\MR`, that with or without `\protect` causes an infinite loop.

Solution: make it `\protected`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsrefs,etoolbox}

\robustify\MR

\begin{document}

\cite{Burkholder1986a-citable-whole-journal}

\cite{Burkholder1986a-citable-article-example}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
\bib*{Burkholder1986a-not-citable}{article}{
  conference={
    title={C.I.M.E. Lectures},
    address={Varenna, Italy},
    date={1985}
  },
  book={
    series={Lecture Notes in Math.},
    volume={1206},
    publisher={Springer-Verlag},
    address={Berlin and New York},
    date={1986},
  },
  review={\MR{0864712}}
}

\bib{Burkholder1986a-citable-whole-journal}{article}{
  xref={Burkholder1986a-not-citable},
}

\bib{Burkholder1986a-citable-article-example}{article}{
  xref={Burkholder1986a-not-citable},
  author={Burkholder, Donald L.},
  title={Martingales and Fourier analysis in Banach spaces},
  pages={61--108},
}
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

This seems to be a bug in `amsrefs` (which I cannot recommend, as `biblatex` is more powerful and well maintained).

[image]

Comment: thank you very much sir. your solution on \MR worked.

perhaps i will also explore the biblatex package.

as regards \MakeUppercase, sometimes some bibliographic styles convert all words in the title into lowercase. the presence of \MakeUppercase makes me think that i can force some letters to be capitalized (like proper nouns, names of persons, places, etc.) even if the chosen bibliographic style forces letters to be lowercased

Comment: so perhaps the authors of amsrefs can fix the bug in future versions

Comment: @beethovengg14 I don’t think that `amsrefs` is being developed or even maintained.

Answer (score 2):

`\MakeUppercase` is already latex robust but amsrefs seems to expand it at the wrong time anyway. It's not clear why you want `\MakeUppercase{L}` at all but you can use etex `\protected` here if you do need it for some reason.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\protected\def\zzz{\MakeUppercase}
\begin{document}
\cite{Burkholder1986a-citable-whole-journal}
\cite{Burkholder1986a-citable-article-example}
\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
\bib*{Burkholder1986a-not-citable}{article}{
conference={
title={C.I.M.E. \zzz{L}ectures},
address={Varenna, Italy},
date={1985}
},
book={
series={Lecture Notes in Math.},
volume={1206},
publisher={Springer-Verlag},
address={Berlin and New York},
date={1986},
},
review={MR{0864712}}
}

\bib{Burkholder1986a-citable-whole-journal}{article}{
xref={Burkholder1986a-not-citable},
}

\bib{Burkholder1986a-citable-article-example}{article}{
xref={Burkholder1986a-not-citable},
author={Burkholder, Donald L.},
title={Martingales and Fourier analysis in Banach spaces},
pages={61--108},
}
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you sir. my concern on \MakeUppercase was solved. as regards \MakeUppercase, sometimes some bibliographic styles convert all words in the title into lowercase. the presence of \MakeUppercase makes me think that i can force some letters to be capitalized (like proper nouns, names of persons, places, etc.) even if the chosen bibliographic style forces letters to be lowercased

Comment: yes sir, i agree with you that \MakeUppercase is already latex robust. it thus surprised why it is causing an error here